# Converting mongoexport json to XML

Tags: c#, json, xml, mongodb, json.net

I export data from our mongoDb database into json file, and need to parse it to XML in order to be usable in our ETL.

Here is a sample of code I try to use to parse one line of my json export :

```
var json = @"{""_id"":{""$oid"":""592bbd86b029e62830c5020a""},""DraftNumber"":""A1B1CB8D"",""ProductRange"":""COMPREHENSIVE_HOME_INSURANCE"",""DraftStatus"":""QUOTATION_DRAFT"",""DraftLabel"":"""",""LastUpdateDate"":{""$date"":""2017-05-29T06:19:53.559Z""},""EndDate"":{""$date"":""2017-07-28T06:19:53.559Z""},""UserId"":""D900036"",""ProjectNumber"":""38764496"",""Identifier"":"""",""CurrencyCode"":""EUR"",""RenewalDate"":{""$date"":""0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z""},""RenewalDay"":0,""RenewalMounth"":0,""CreationDate"":{""$date"":""2017-05-29T06:19:50.138Z""},""EffectiveHour"":""0"",""EffectiveMinute"":""0"",""HasAs"":[{""_t"":""AgreementHolder"",""_id"":{""$oid"":""000000000000000000000000""},""DistribCustomer"":{""isProspect"":true}}],""IsBasedOnProduct"":{""pricingType"":""DISCOUNT_RATE"",""pricingVersion"":""C""},""ActivityInAgreements"":[{""_t"":""AgreementRequest"",""_id"":{""$oid"":""000000000000000000000000""},""PremiumNature"":null}],""OriginalSubscriptionChannel"":""DIRECT"",""CurrentSubscriptionChannel"":""DIRECT"",""BusinessExpirationDate"":{""$date"":""0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z""},""TechnicalExpirationDate"":{""$date"":""2017-08-27T06:19:53.559Z""},""IsEligibleToProposal"":true,""IneligibityReasonCodes"":[],""DematerialisationOfDocuments"":true}";

var doc = (XmlDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json);

Console.WriteLine(doc);
Console.ReadKey();
```

And i face the following exception :

> L'exception Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException n'a pas été
>   gérée   HResult=-2146233088   Message=JSON root object has multiple
>   properties. The root object must have a single property in order to
>   create a valid XML document. Consider specifying a
>   DeserializeRootElementName. Path 'DraftNumber', line 1, position 57.
>   Source=Newtonsoft.Json   StackTrace:
>          à Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.XmlNodeConverter.DeserializeNode(JsonReader
>   reader, IXmlDocument document, XmlNamespaceManager manager, IXmlNode
>   currentNode)
>          à Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.XmlNodeConverter.ReadJson(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer
>   serializer)
>          à Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.DeserializeConvertable(JsonConverter
>   converter, JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue)
>          à Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
>          à Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
>          à Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
>          à Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonConverter[] converters)
>          à Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(String value, String deserializeRootElementName, Boolean writeArrayAttribute)
>          à Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(String value)
>          à ConsoleApplication3.Program.Main(String[] args) dans c:\documents\s638723\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication3\Program.cs:ligne 17
>          à System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>          à System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          à Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          à System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          à System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException:

More globally i'm wondering if the type exported by `mongoexport` is usable by the jsonconverter.

Comment: @jdweng are you sure ? https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeXmlNode.htm

Comment: A well formed Xml has one tag at root level.  Your JSON has an array at the root level.  So the conversion is giving an error because the resultant xml has more than one element at the root.  For code to work you would need to wrapped the Json with a root : {"Root" :  {
  "_id": {.........}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the exception states, JSON has `multiple` properties at top level.

Simply define `root` like:

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("Json_1.json"))
{
    string json = r.ReadToEnd();
    var doc = (XmlDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json, "root");
}
```

**Output:**

```
<root>
    <_id>
        <_x0024_oid>592bbd86b029e62830c5020a</_x0024_oid>
    </_id>
    <DraftNumber>A1B1CB8D</DraftNumber>
    <ProductRange>COMPREHENSIVE_HOME_INSURANCE</ProductRange>
    <DraftStatus>QUOTATION_DRAFT</DraftStatus>
    <DraftLabel/>
    <LastUpdateDate>
        <_x0024_date>2017-05-29T06:19:53.559Z</_x0024_date>
    </LastUpdateDate>
    <EndDate>
        <_x0024_date>2017-07-28T06:19:53.559Z</_x0024_date>
    </EndDate>
    <UserId>D900036</UserId>
    <ProjectNumber>38764496</ProjectNumber>
    <Identifier/>
    <CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode>
    <RenewalDate>
        <_x0024_date>0001-01-01T00:00:00Z</_x0024_date>
    </RenewalDate>
    <RenewalDay>0</RenewalDay>
    <RenewalMounth>0</RenewalMounth>
    <CreationDate>
        <_x0024_date>2017-05-29T06:19:50.138Z</_x0024_date>
    </CreationDate>
    <EffectiveHour>0</EffectiveHour>
    <EffectiveMinute>0</EffectiveMinute>
    <HasAs>
        <_t>AgreementHolder</_t>
        <_id>
            <_x0024_oid>000000000000000000000000</_x0024_oid>
        </_id>
        <DistribCustomer>
            <isProspect>true</isProspect>
        </DistribCustomer>
    </HasAs>
    <IsBasedOnProduct>
        <pricingType>DISCOUNT_RATE</pricingType>
        <pricingVersion>C</pricingVersion>
    </IsBasedOnProduct>
    <ActivityInAgreements>
        <_t>AgreementRequest</_t>
        <_id>
            <_x0024_oid>000000000000000000000000</_x0024_oid>
        </_id>
        <PremiumNature />
    </ActivityInAgreements>
    <OriginalSubscriptionChannel>DIRECT</OriginalSubscriptionChannel>
    <CurrentSubscriptionChannel>DIRECT</CurrentSubscriptionChannel>
    <BusinessExpirationDate>
        <_x0024_date>0001-01-01T00:00:00Z</_x0024_date>
    </BusinessExpirationDate>
    <TechnicalExpirationDate>
        <_x0024_date>2017-08-27T06:19:53.559Z</_x0024_date>
    </TechnicalExpirationDate>
    <IsEligibleToProposal>true</IsEligibleToProposal>
    <DematerialisationOfDocuments>true</DematerialisationOfDocuments>
</root>
```